# UnionFind implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, set, union-find

The Wikipedia article on the [union find problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_find) gives a very simple implementation, which I ported to C# and tested.

I know that the code should be, in the aggregate, asymptotically almost linear. But is it a practical implementation? Are there optimizations I should have used? Is there a way to cut down on the worst-case complexity of single operations?

```
using System;

/// <summary>
/// A UnionFindNode represents a set of nodes that it is a member of.
/// 
/// You can get the unique representative node of the set a given node is in by using the Find method.
/// Two nodes are in the same set when their Find methods return the same representative.
/// The IsUnionedWith method will check if two nodes' sets are the same (i.e. the nodes have the same representative).
///
/// You can merge the sets two nodes are in by using the Union operation.
/// There is no way to split sets after they have been merged.
/// </summary>
public class UnionFindNode {
    private UnionFindNode _parent;
    private uint _rank;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new disjoint node, representative of a set containing only the new node.
    /// </summary>
    public UnionFindNode() {
        _parent = this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the current representative of the set this node is in.
    /// Note that the representative is only accurate untl the next Union operation.
    /// </summary>
    public UnionFindNode Find() {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_parent, this)) _parent = _parent.Find();
        return _parent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether or not this node and the other node are in the same set.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsUnionedWith(UnionFindNode other) {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        return ReferenceEquals(Find(), other.Find());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Merges the sets represented by this node and the other node into a single set.
    /// Returns whether or not the nodes were disjoint before the union operation (i.e. if the operation had an effect).
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True when the union had an effect, false when the nodes were already in the same set.</returns>
    public bool Union(UnionFindNode other) {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        var root1 = this.Find();
        var root2 = other.Find();
        if (ReferenceEquals(root1, root2)) return false;

        if (root1._rank < root2._rank) {
            root1._parent = root2;
        } else if (root1._rank > root2._rank) {
            root2._parent = root1;
        } else {
            root2._parent = root1;
            root1._rank++;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. If I read the wikipedia article correctly then the algorithm should have amortized constant cost - and you have implemented it pretty much 1:1. Given that with your implementation you always start with disjoint nodes and any call to any of the public methods ends up calling `Find` which will automatically flatten the tree I doubt you can get much better.
2. `UnionFindNode` is not a particularly good name for the data structure: intermingles operations with the data structure in the name. Just `Node` or maybe `DisjointSetNode` would be better.
3. You could use `==` or `!=` instead of `ReferenceEquals` which would make the code a bit easier to read.
4. Consider making your node class generic and add a `T value` property - right now your nodes are not all that useful as they don't hold any data.

Comment: Considering that the data structure is commonly called the Union-Find data structure, I think the class name is OK.

Comment: For #4: The idea I had in mind is to put the node *inside* the target class, to hide implementation details, instead of putting the target inside the node. Because you can't explore the set, given a node, it's not very useful to put the value there.

Comment: @Strilanc: Well, with a little bit more effort and some memory you can explore the set without changing the basic properties of the algorithm.

Comment: @200_success: Hm, fair enough, I guess in this case the kind of structure and the operations you perform on it are very closely related.

Comment: Do you think, that the fact that `Find` method is recursive may be a problem (stack overflow) with deep trees?